# Pandas to_dict() custom format

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
   id         age
0  10002145   68
1  10005414   44
2  10007083   61
3  10008103   60
```

and I'm trying to format the output into:

```
[
    {'id': 10002145, 'age': {'value': 68, 'timestamp': '2018-01-01T00:00:00'}},
    {'id': 10005414, 'age': {'value': 44, 'timestamp': '2018-01-01T00:00:00'}},
    ...
]
```

So basically what I need is to convert the `age` column into a dictionary with the appended timestamp. Now I can get very close with `df.to_dict(orient='records')` but what can I do to convert the `age` column to the specified format ?

Thanks

Comment: Where does the "timestamp" value come from?  It's not in your original dataframe (from the example you posted).

Comment: @payne: it's a constan value, `datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Comprehension

```
[{'id': i, 'age': {'value': v, 'timestamp': '2018-01-01'}} for i, v in zip(df.id, df.age)]

[{'age': {'timestamp': '2018-01-01', 'value': 68}, 'id': 10002145},
 {'age': {'timestamp': '2018-01-01', 'value': 44}, 'id': 10005414},
 {'age': {'timestamp': '2018-01-01', 'value': 61}, 'id': 10007083},
 {'age': {'timestamp': '2018-01-01', 'value': 60}, 'id': 10008103}]
```